# How to do a fuzzy search in Redis

Tags: redis

I want to do a fuzzy search in Redis

I have lots of Domain-IP info to maintain, and I want to use a hash to hold them

The structure of Domain-IP is sth like this:

Domain-IP

> domain
>
> ip
>
> last-access (last time I use this ip to access the domain)
>
> access-count
>
> ...

Now I want to do two things:

1. search this Domain-IP info by domain, sth like: select * from domain-ip where domain = "www.google.com"
2. update Domain-IP info by domain and IP, sth like: update domain-ip set access-count = access-count + 1 where domain = "www.google.com" and ip = "192.168.1.1"

so my design the structure in Redis is:

```
HSET domainip.www.google.com.192.168.1.1 access-count 20

HSET domainip.www.google.com.192.168.1.2 access-count 20
```

so I can serach them by domain like this, for example, search info about www.google.com:

1. get all keys starts with www.google.com by : keys domainip.www.google.com*
2. use these keys to get all the info about google in a loop:

> ```
> for (string key : keys) {
>    execute("HGETALL " + key) // then convert the hash into a POJO
> }
> ```

and the update operation as follow:

> "HSET domainip." + domainStr + "." + ipStr + " access-count " +
>   newAccessCount;
>
> "HSET domainip." + domainStr + "." + ipStr + " last-access " +
>   newLastAccess;

My question is :

1. Does the loop causes performance issue?
2. Is that right to update the hash filed one by one?

It will be nice if you can provide a good idea to complete the operation what I want in Redis, Thx :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys is not recommended for production use (see http://redis.io/commands/keys).  My first instinct is that you actually want a SQL database here, Redis doesn't lend itself to arbitrary slicing of data the way you're describing.

If you really need to use redis for some reason, you're going to need to maintain a bunch of indexes for access.  Basically, every "where clause" you want to use will get a set (or sorted set, if you need a specific ordering) maintaining the list of hashes matching that key.  So, for example, if you have hashes

```
domainip.www.google.com.192.168.1.1
domainip.www.google.com.192.168.1.2
domainip.www.yahoo.com.192.168.1.4
```

You would make index sets:

```
by_domain:www.google.com => (
         domainip.www.google.com.192.168.1.1,
         domainip.www.google.com.192.168.1.2
)
by_domain:www.yahoo.com => (
         domainip.www.yahoo.com.192.168.1.4
)
```

Where the values of the sets are the keys of your hash, and the keys of the sets are the queries in `<column>:<value>` format.  You'll need to maintain these indexes as you add and remove hash keys.